# Static method imports in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can a method be statically imported in Kotlin? For example, in Java it's possible to do:

```
...
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
...
class FoobarTest {
     ...
     @Test public void testFoo() {
          verify(mock).doSomething();
     } 
}
```

How can the same be done in Kotlin without having to fully qualify the method every time with `Mockito.verify(mock).doSomething()`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It turns out it's very easy. To import a single static method:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito.verify
```

And to import everything:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito.*
```

so it will be possible to do

```
`when`(someMock.someAction).thenReturn(someResult)
verify(mock).doSomething()
```

Comment: Wish alt+enter on IntelliJ let you import static like it does with Java!

Comment: Was looking for how to call Mockito's static when function rather than Kotlin's when keyword... using back ticks. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jire it does, you just have to put cursor on Mockito then you will have option: 'Import members from *'

Comment: @HappyDev at least here it will use an wildcard import for that class, and for some (me included) that is not ideal. But thanks for the tip.